# What is this color bar for in htop page

Tags: htop

I have a 48-CPU UBUNTU and it has loaded with lots of processes. Here is the htop page,
[image]

At core section, the green bar means the usage from normal user, the red one represents the kernel usage, but what is the 3rd color stands for ? Thanks.

Here is what I have seen on the same terminal when I click F1 button.
[image]

Comment: Does your terminal use non standard colors?

Comment: I don't think so. Let's think it differently.  If it was not green, nor red, what would it be ?  What is the other options here ?

Answer (score 7):

htop has multiple color schemes that get defined in `~/.config/htop/htoprc` which is inherited from `/etc/htoprc`  However it is not recommended to edit these files manually as the configuration can be changed via the in-program setup configuration (press <kbd>F2</kbd> in the program to access this).

You can see what your current color scheme is by pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> inside the program.

The default color scheme is:

- Dark Blue – Indicates CPU percentage used by low priority processes. Low processes in htop are indicated by an exit value of greater than 0.
- Green – shows processes running as regular users in the system.
- Red – shows kernel threads.
- Aqua Blue – shows virtualized processes.

Comment: I've never touched that "~/.config/htop/htoprc" file, so it should be whatever the original settings are.  And when I press "F1" on htop,  I do see the message about which cloud matches with what type of process, and it  displays exactly like the one on this page,  https://www.cloudsavvyit.com/7847/color-bars-in-htop-what-do-they-mean/,  and that is why I am confused for the 3rd bar color on my htop page.

Comment: I agree. but the  color I listed does not match any of these.

Comment: I have just updated my original post when  F1 button is clicked on the same terminal.

Comment: @user3595231: strange, not sure what your issue is but I'll leave my answer up incase someone else with a similar issue stumbles on this.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "excellent value"?

Comment: @asgs sorry I'm sure I meant exit

Comment: ah, that makes sense :-) thank you!

Comment: I can't understand "exit value". Shouldn't that be "nice value"?