# How to interpret the colors in htop's memory bar?

Tags: linux, htop

I have the following htop output:

[image]

What are the green, blue, and yellow bars respectively in this memory output?

Comment: [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/180711/what-exactly-do-the-colors-in-htop-status-bars-mean)

Comment: This comment somehow got deleted: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/698514/what-is-this-color-bar-for-in-htop-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in htop, press F1 for the color key as well as a lot of other information